# Delete function of JPArepository in Spring boot does not work , What is the reason?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In the previous tests, I saw that while it was able to delete without any problems, it does not work now.

This is my entity class :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="subcomments")
public class SubComment {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;
    
    @Column(name="uid")
    public String uid;
    
    @Column (name="name")
    public String name;
    
    @Column (name="above_uid")
    public String above_uid;
    
    @Column (name="url")
    public String url;
    
    @Column(name="coin")
    public String coin;
    
    @Column (name="comment")
    public String comment;
    
    @Column (name="top_date")
    public int top_date;
    
    @Column (name="top_time")
    public int top_time;
}
```

This is my jpa repository :

```
public interface SubCommentRepo extends JpaRepository<SubComment , Long>{
    
    // All CRUD database methods
    
    @Query( value="Select * from subcomments where uid=:uid and above_uid=:above_uid and coin=:coin and comment=:comment and top_date=:top_date and top_time=:top_time" , nativeQuery=true )
    public SubComment info(String uid, String above_uid, String coin, String comment,int top_date, int top_time);
}
```

The info method in the repository is designed to check the existence of the current data in the database.

This is my rest controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/user")
public class ServiceController {
    
    @Autowired 
    SubCommentRepo subRepo ;
    
    // Delete Sub Comment ***
    @DeleteMapping(path="/comment/sub/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<String> delete( @RequestBody SubComment smt ) {
        
        if ( subRepo.info(smt.uid, smt.above_uid, smt.coin, smt.comment, smt.top_date, smt.top_time)!= null ) {
            
            subRepo.delete(smt);
            
            return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.OK ).body ( "Deleted" );
            
        } else {
            
            return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST ).body( "Not available already" );
        }
    }
}
```

I am using mysql as database.

I am trying spring boot for the first time. :)

Comment: Has the passed object the `id` filled? Otherwise JPA does not know which object to delete.

Comment: @puelo normally it doesn't work even if I write a delete query

Comment: Try:   subRepo.delete(smt.getId());

Comment: As you cited: "it doesn't work even if I write a delete query" - what is the error content emmited by your sql executor? For example: if it is a MySql Constraint Violation it seems that you primary key id is a foreign key in other table (in this case you would to unrelate them before removing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `deleteById` method instead of the `delete` method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/user")
public class ServiceController {
    
    @Autowired 
    SubCommentRepo subRepo ;
    
    // Delete Sub Comment ***
    @DeleteMapping(path="/comment/sub/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<String> delete( @RequestBody SubComment smt ) {
        
        if ( subRepo.info(smt.uid, smt.above_uid, smt.coin, smt.comment, smt.top_date, smt.top_time)!= null ) {
            
            subRepo.deleteById(smt.id);
            
            return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.OK ).body ( "Deleted" );
            
        } else {
            
            return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST ).body( "Not available already" );
        }
    }
}
```